# How to ensure OS X app Entitlements are applied?

Tags: xcode, macos, appstore-sandbox, code-signing-entitlements

I've configured Entitlements in Xcode, but they don't get put in the compiled app bundle. Do I have to do some additional steps?

I'm writing an OS X "Developer ID"-signed application (*not* for the AppStore), and to be able to implement an Extension that shares preferences with the parent app I need to put them in the same App Group.

I've configured App Groups in Xcode, and I see them in `$Extension.entitlements` and `$ParentApp.entitlements` plist.

However, in the built product `$Extension.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeEntitlements` resembles a default entitlements file without the group I've configured, and in the parent app this file doesn't exist at all.

I've even tried signing the app again with an explicit entitlements file:

```
codesign --force --entitlements $ParentApp.entitlements -s "Developer ID" \
   Build/Products/Debug/$ParentApp.app
```

but again, it doesn't get added to `$ParentApp.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeEntitlements`.

At run time the parent app and the extension don't appear to be in the same app group: they write their preferences (`[NSUserDefaults…initWithSuiteName:teamIdEtc]`) to their own subdirectories in `~/Library/Containers` rather than a shared dir in `~/Library/Group Containers`.

Comment: Are both apps listed under the key `<key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>`?

Comment: @l'L'l they are not. The documentation says the app group is in the format TEAMID.someidentifier, so that's what I've used.

Comment: That's what I was meaning; Is the app group container getting created? It might be normal for each app to write `NSUserDefaults` to their own containers since the description of the app group container only mentions:  "This container is intended for content that is not user-facing, such as shared caches or databases" — which could possibly explain the behavior perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magically, it started to work after:

- I've replaced `$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)` with actual identifier
- Deleted `DerivedData` folders everywhere and rebuilt everything